# Smooth scrolling to HTML bookmark

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarks

I have the following markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blah</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id='navigation'>
            <nav>
                <a rel='bookmark' href='#introduction'>Home</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section id='content'>
            <section id='introduction'>
                <header>
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <a href='#navigation'>Back to top></a>
                </header>
            </section>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

So you can click on `Home` and get to the `introduction` section with a bookmark.  You can then get back to the `navigation` by clicking `Back to top`.

This will work in all browsers.

What I want to do is add a javascript listener somehow so that if Javascript is enabled on the browser it listens for bookmarks and smooth scrolls to the bookmark.

Thinking out loud, I could add an `onchange` listener to the location bar, parse the location and check for anything after a `#`.  I could get the element `id` of the text after this character and implement a smooth scrolling algorithm? I don't think this would negate the UA scrolling however.

I could also parse the DOM for links that contain `#` links and add javascript onclick `smoothScoll(bookmark_name)` events and remove the bookmark so the link will just be `'#'` then in the `smoothScroll` do the scrolling and add it to the location bar after the #.

I would like to learn to do this with javascript and not jQuery.

Anyone got any ideas for doing this.  I want to leave the HTML as is and add javascript events in my `initPage()` which means that I **know** javascript is enabled.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: This is simple if you use jQuery. Do you have to have a non-jQuery answer?

Comment: I'd just rather understand how to manipulate the DOM in this way as I would like to use the HTML5 History API and will allow me tighter customisation of my JS code for the website I'm doing.  I'll figure it out this weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click listener on your `a#href` elements, and ensure that the click returns **false**, this way you will negate the UA scroll. After that, you'll have to manually scroll or animate the scrolling property to match the link's offsetTop.

Here's a js fiddle using jQuery to get you going: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtbVQ/1/. You only have to translate the jQuery calls to pure js calls.

Comment: Ok I'll have a look at what jQuery does.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jquery scroll:

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

This should let you do what you want.  Here is a good overview on useage:

http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery ideally, I want to work it out with normal Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

> With this plugin, you will easily
>   scroll overflowed elements, and the
>   screen itself. It gives you access to
>   many different options to customize
>   and various ways to specify where to
>   scroll.